# C -- number of elements in an array?

Tags: c

Suppose that I have the following `c` function:

```
int MyFunction( const float arr[] )
{
    // define a variable to hold the number of items in 'arr'
    int numItems = ...;

    // do something here, then return...

    return 1

}
```

How can I get into `numItems` the number of items that are in the array `arr`?

Comment: I remember that I used to make size as another argument for such kind of functions..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of elements in static array and dynamic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577711/number-of-elements-in-static-array-and-dynamic-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get it. In C, the following 2 are equivalent declarations.

```
int MyFunction( const float arr[] );
int MyFunction( const float* arr );
```

You must pass the size on your own.

```
int MyFunction( const float* arr, int nSize );
```

In case of `char` pointers designating strings the length of the char array is determined by delimiter `'\0'`.

Comment: Great answer. Which function definition is preferred: the first one (`using arr[]`) or the second one (`using *arr[]`)?

Comment: @user3262424: You mistyped in your comment - be careful! :) I think choosing between `float arr[]` and `float*` to pass an array is a matter of taste

Comment: Thank you Armen. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 5):

Either you pass the number of elements in another argument or you have some convention on a delimiting element in the array.

Answer (score 5):

I initially suggested this:

```
 int numItems = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(float);
```

[But it will not work](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays#sizeof) since `arr` is not defined in the current context and it's being interpreted as a simple pointer. **So in this case, you will have to give the number of elements as parameter**. The suggested statement would otherwise work in the following context:

```
int MyFunction()
{
     float arr[10];
     int numItems = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(float);
     return numItems;// returns 10
}
```

Comment: arr is a function argument. It's just a pointer, not an array — won't work. http://ideone.com/sQqWP

Comment: This is incorrect. `arr` is not of type `float []` when it is a function parameter. Instead it is `float *`.

Comment: @Susam: May that's what I said?

Comment: @sidyll Yes, we are saying the same things here. +1-ed you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The number will have to be passed to `MyFunction` separately. So add a second argument to MyFunction which should contain the size.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, passing it as another argument seems to be only solution. Otherwise you can have a globally defined convention.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you have some predetermined format of the array. Because potentially you can have any number of float. And with the `const float arr[]` you only pass the array's base address to the function of type `float []` which cannot be modified. So you can do `arr[n]` for any `n` .

Answer (score 1):

better than

```
int numItems = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(float);
```

is

```
int numItems = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
```