# Count the number of duplicate elements in an array - C

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

Take a input from user in an Array of a size N and print the total number of duplicate elements (The elements which occur two or more times).

Input Format: The first line contains N. The second line contains the N positive integer separated by a space.

Output Format: Count of duplicate elements.

The program I wrote works for only two same elements and fails to read more than 2 duplicates.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[1000],i,j,n,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {
                count=count+1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);

}
```

Input (for an eight-digit example):

```
1 2 3 1 2 1 5 6
```

Incorrect output of this code:

```
3
```

The expected output is 2, the count of elements which has duplicates (1 has two duplicates and 2 has one duplicate).

So please explain what am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you allowed to sort it first?

Comment: @Bathsheba yes.

Comment: Well, once you've sorted it, it's a matter of traversing the array and checking if an element is the same as the one before it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count repeated elements in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851716/count-repeated-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: What output you expect 5? 3(Count of 1) + 2(Count of 2)?

Comment: @cse Output expected is 2.   count of elements which has duplicates(1 has     two duplicates and 2 has one duplicate). count(1,2)

Comment: You should define *the count of duplicate elements* better - you want to count the number of digits that have more than one occurrence? In your case, digits `1` and `2` have more than one occurrence each, therefore returns `2` digits?

Comment: Also, the assignment begs for dynamic array allocation with "The first line contains N". What if `N=1001` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code for the same. It first sorts the array:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[1000],i,j,n,count=0, min;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[min]>arr[j])
            {
                min = j;    
            }
        }
        {
            int temp = arr[min];
            arr[min] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==arr[i-1])
        {
            count++;
            while(arr[i]==arr[i-1]) i++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);

    return 0;
}
```

You can [find it working here](http://ideone.com/qWOH3V)

Answer (score 0):

Your count increase when `i==0&&j==4`, `i==0&&j==6` and again at `i==4&j==6`. When the third check is redundant. So to resolve that put in a `i<j` condition and break to stop checking the already checked elements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[1000],i,j,n,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(arr[i]==arr[j]&& i!=j){
               if(i<j){
                    count=count+1;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below java program takes less time and it is very flexible, increase the y array size based on the number in x array.

```
public void countDuplicates() {
    int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,9,1,0,9,1,1,2,4};
    int[] y = new int[10];
    for(int i =0 ; i< x.length ; i++) {
        y[x[i]] = y[x[i]] + 1;
    }
    int c = 0;
    for (int a:y) {
        System.out.println(c+"---> "+a);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question asked in `C` not in `java`

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code, It will write -1 in place of all the duplicates of an element and hence it will count the elements having duplicates only once.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter The Size of the Array ";
    cin >> n;
    int *a = new int[n];
    cout << "Enter The Elements of the Array\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];
    int count = 0;
    bool duplicate = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        duplicate = false;
        if(a[i] == -1) continue;
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            if(a[j] == a[i]) {
                duplicate = true;
                a[j] = -1;
            }
        }
        if(duplicate) count++;
    }
    cout << count ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question asked in `C` not in `C++` . Also do format answer well.